# regexp numbers before and after '-'

Tags: matlab

1) I have figure names and numbers in the following format: 'Figure number-number: letters/numbers/_s'.  For example, 'Figure 10-11: speed_of_20_cars'.

I got this far shown below:

```
regexp(cell2mat(regexp('Figure 10-11: speed_of_20_cars','[0-9]+-[0-9]+','match')),'(?<!:)-(?!:)','split')
```

The above gives a cell of two doubles: 10 and 11.  So, it works, but there's gotta be a way to do all this with one regexp.

2) The format is: 'Figure 10: speed_of_20_cars'.  I have:

```
strrep(regexp('Figure 10: speed_of_20_cars','[0-9]+:','match'),':','')
```

which gives a cell of a double: 10.  Again, there's gotta be a way to do this with just one regexp.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
s=regexp('Figure 10-11: speed_of_20_cars','([0-9]+)[-:]','tokens')
ids=cellfun(@str2num,[s{:}])
```

Comment: yes.  Thank you.  ah..'token'.  never used it.  how does [-:] work with 'token'?  i think it means '-' or ':', but how does it know whether it's before/after/between?

Comment: the `'tokens'` option basically returns the variable you defined using the `()` operator. I am asking regexp to find numbers followed by either "-" (the first number) or ":" (the 2nd number). see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/tokens-in-regular-expressions.html